# Can/Should I Move These Pipes?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe

I need to fix a broken ball valve (luckily the valve doesn't leak until I turn it on) that runs to an outside faucet. Also, all of these pipes are CPVC.

When I looked at replacing it, they seemed to have gone a roundabout way of doing it.  Can I route it differently?

Current Configuration:
[image: Current Configuration]

Another View:
[image: Another View]

Proposed Configuration:
[image]

I prefer to run it straight up and to just put a 90 on the other side of the beam (ie don't go through the beam).

- Will this cause pressure issues (either through the outside faucet or
  the rest of the house)?
- Why did they do this?

Comment: My guess - amateur junior plumber.

Comment: First this question had great pictures.  Second plumbers I know love going through framing - 2 guesses on this.  It secures the line (I know there are many other ways to do that) and they get paid by the hour a lot.  Why not drill some holes and make a job take another 30 mins.

Comment: @DMoore - The configuration as built does make the line that goes off to the outside faucet very secure. From the image it would appear that the line goes directly out to the outside wall of the house. This configuration allows the line to take some abuse from the outside when the spigot in the outside gets some strain from pulling via a hose or some such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with moving it to your suggested configuration.  They probably went through the framing to make the entire configuration more secure.  Make sure if you change it to make sure that you clamp it to the framing to make sure there isn't room for movement.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll remember to clamp it to the framing.  It looked odd to me, too.

Answer (score 4):

No change in pressure, may be a (very) slight increase in flow (1 less elbow).

No idea why.  Perhaps they were trying out a new wood boring bit.